# Vue custom number input component using 0.01 step updates int values only

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My small custom number input works fine using a transparent wrapper.
But when I change the `step` value to `0.01` it will only update for whole integer values.

https://codepen.io/luaiodu/pen/BOVLbM?editors=1111

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using need this.$emit('input', Number.parseFloat(val.target.value))

Comment: Yes, I have overlooked that completely! But I wonder whether it's good to do either parseFloat or parseInt based on the step value?